# How do I remove the Finder context option after removing an app?

Tags: finder, shortcut-menu

I got an app a long time ago (called [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)) that adds an option to Finder's context menu. The way I installed the app was by simply moving it to my Applications folder, and it didn't come with an uninstaller. I transferred all my stuff to my new computer via Time Machine, and the option in Finder is unfortunately still there. How can I get rid of it without re-installing the operating system?

See the last option in this context menu:
[image: Finder context option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in `~/Library/Services/`. It probably installed a service there that didn't get uninstalled. You can safely delete the file.

If you don't find anything there, look in **System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Services** for an entry with the same name as the context menu item. Right-click that entry and it will offer you a *Show in Finder* option, from which you can delete the file.

Comment: Great! There is no folder called "Services" in `~/Library/Application Support/`, but I found the keyboard preferences to be very useful. I was able to disable the options like I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that should be `~/Library/Services/`. I'll correct the answer.